# connecting to mysql in docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to connect to `MYSQL DB` in a `Docker Container` but I'm getting this error

```
[HY000][1130] null,  message from server: "Host '172.17.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server".
```

I'm connecting using the user `root` so I edited the `host` for it in `mysql.user` table to be `%` rather `localhost`, but still can't connect, also I reviewed the `port bindings`  for the container both container and host `3306:3306`, I can't find any other reasons preventing me from connecting, anything else I have to check or solution to this issue ?

Comment: Seeing your docker-compose.yml or the k8s equivalent would help to understand what exactly you are trying to connect to and where from. Also seeing the code / config you are using would also help: What is your setup? Are you connecting to the server through the host port or container-to-container on the same network? Can you use the same credentials to connect locally when logged into the container?

Comment: Also, typically, root user can only connect from the localhost. Although you suggest you have probably done something in that sense, you may want to run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@my_ip IDENTIFIED BY ‘root_password‘ WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Comment: Last, but not least, I'd recommend not using root anyway - set up another account and leave the root for local connections only.

Comment: @vch , I'm using Intellij to connect to the DB , also I tried `MySQL -u root -ppasssword;` and I was able to connect to the DB, I'm also using the Intellij to manage the containers and images, the container is on my local HDD

Comment: It seems that you are saying that you can connect successfully using IntelliJ and mysql. So what code is not able to connect and where is this code running (container, your bare machine, for example)?